# What is the "Stack" section in gdb

Tags: assembly, stack, gdb, callstack, backtrace

In gdb, it seems that whatever is located in the "Stack" section is always the same as the `%rip` register. For example:

```
rip 0x0000555555554603
─── Stack ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[0] from 0x0000555555554603 in main
```

And after doing `si`:

```
rip 0x0000555555554606
─── Stack ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
[0] from 0x0000555555554606 in main
```

What exactly is the "Stack" section in gdb? It seems to me like it is more-or-less the instruction pointer (`%rip`) in the currently running function (and previous `%rip`s in the call stack that have not completed execution). Is this correct, or what does this section tell us?

If useful, here is the front-end that I'm using in gdb, which is called [`gdb dashboard`](https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard):

[image]

Comment: How did you get GDB to display that?  Is that some front-end, or part of GDB's TUI mode?  It's not part of the normal TUI `layout reg` display.  But anyway, it looks like output from GDB's `bt` (`backtrace`) command.

Comment: @PeterCordes updated question with an example of it

Comment: Ok, so that's a gdb-dashboard feature.  Probably just showing you the output of `bt` or `frame` to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the call stack. GDB enables you to see the call stack, so you can understand how you got to where you are (Which function calls did you go through to get to where you are).

The call stack is the list of functions that have been called and not yet returned, beginning with the current function at frame 0, and going all the way down to main at the last frame.

In your particular case, your call stack is only main, because you've not called other functions (or because they returned already). %rip points to the current instruction, so your location in the current frame always corresponds to its contents.

Comment: thanks for this explanation. In the call stack, what's the correct terminology to refer to a parent or child function? For example, if I'm at frame 1, what is the term for the function at frame 0? at frame 2 or higher?

Comment: GDB refers to it as going "up" or "down" one frame, with "up" bringing you one level up, to the function that called you, and "down" bringing you one level down, to a function that you called. I don't think there's another term other than "up" or "down".

Comment: thanks, outside of gdb (in c or asm for example) is there a convention other than up/down ?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249: Your caller is the "parent" function.  When you `frame 1` up into your parent, `frame 0` is its "child".  The call graph of a whole program is often somewhat like a tree, but in the general case it's a directed graph which can include cycles.  (e.g. co-recursive functions, callbacks.)